# ¿Cómo obtener el resultado de un procedimiento almacenado en Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedure

tengo una duda, espero y me puedan ayudar, lo que pasa es que estoy manejando transacciones en mysql para poder verificar que se haya ingresado toda la información y no existan datos huerfanos, lo que quiere saber es como le puedo mandar el valor de una variable que tengo declarada en mysql en caso que ocurra una exepcion, estoy manejando laravel, les muestro el codigo y se los explico

PROCEDURE:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE registro_contacto_sucursal
(
  IN
  _sucursal INTEGER,
  _nombre VARCHAR(100),
  _apellido_p VARCHAR(100),
  _apellido_m VARCHAR(100),
  _edad INTEGER,
  _email VARCHAR(100),
  _rfc VARCHAR(15),
  _nacimiento DATE,
  _contacto VARCHAR(20),
  _persona INTEGER,
  _operacion VARCHAR(20)
)BEGIN
  DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback`=1;
  CASE _operacion
  WHEN 'own' THEN

    START TRANSACTION;
      INSERT INTO persona(Nombre,Apellido_p,Apellido_m,Edad,Email,Rfc,Fecha_Nacimiento,Contacto)
      VALUES(_nombre,_apellido_p,apellido_m,_edad,_email,_rfc,_nacimiento,_contacto);

      SET @id_persona=(SELECT Id_Persona FROM persona ORDER BY Id_Persona DESC LIMIT 1);

      INSERT INTO contacto_sucursal(Id_Persona,Id_Sucursal)
      VALUES(@id_persona,_sucursal);
      

    IF `_rollback` THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
    COMMIT;
    END IF;
    
    SELECT `_rollback`;

  WHEN 'exist' THEN
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO contacto_sucursal(Id_Persona,Id_Sucursal)
    VALUES(_persona,_sucursal);

    IF `_rollback` THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
    COMMIT;
    END IF;

  END CASE;
  
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

la variable _rollback es la que cambia de estado al existir un error, si ejecuto directo el procedure desde phpmyadmin me imprime el valor de la variable, lo que intente hacer por medio de laravel fue lo siguiente, para ver si asi podia guardar ese valor y retornarla y asi avisarle al usuario si se realizo la inserccion o no
**LARAVEL**

```
 protected function registerStrangerContact(Request $request)
    {
        
        
        $result=DB::statement('CALL registro_contacto_sucursal(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[
            $request->input('sucursal'),
            $request->input('nombre'),
            $request->input('paterno'),
            $request->input('materno'),
            $request->input('edad'),
            $request->input('email'),
            $request->input('rfc'),
            $request->input('nacimiento'),
            $request->input('telefono'),
            '99999',
            'own'

        ]);
        return $result;
    }
```

por medio de ajax estoy visualizando el valor que regresa pero siempre me regresa 1 a pesar que si se haya hecho la insercción, pero al comparar de modo manual con phpmyadmin me arroja 0, y asi debe de ser puesto que no cambio al no existir una excepcion

codigo en ajax

```
 $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('register_strager_contact')}}",
                method:"POST",
                data:{sucursal:sucursal,nombre:nombre,paterno:paterno,materno:materno,edad:edad,email:email,rfc:rfc,nacimiento:nacimiento,telefono:telefono,_token:_token},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);     
                }
                });
```

espero y me puedan ayudar, ya que al realizar la insercción del lado del usuario no se sabe si se hizo o no, an dado caso se le mandaria un alert o algo para indicarle, muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba hacer el siguiente cambio:

- En lugar de usar el método `statment` que está pensado para consultas que no retornan ningún valor.
- Prueba usar el método `select` para estos casos que siempre nos regresará un array de resultados<sup>1</sup>.

Entonces puedes dejarla así:

```
$condulta = DB::select('CALL tuPA(?, ?)', [$request->valor1, $request->valor2]);
```

Posterior para ver los valores que te devuelve puedes hacer esto:

```
dd($condulta);
```

Desde aquí ya podrás ver qué propiedades te regresa y acceder a la que necesitas para notificar al usuario.

Fuentes de consulta:

- <sup>1</sup>[Ejecutar consultas SQL](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#running-queries)

Comment: gracias, asi es solo era cambiar el statement por el select, muchas gracias, me sirvio bastante