# Error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb, foreach

Tengo el siguiente problema, mi foreach no logra interpretar el resultado de mi stored procedure, el query es el siguiente:

```
$reporte = "call sp_reportes(1,".$request->input('anio').",".$request->input('mes').",0,'null','null');";

return view('Reportes.reporte_mensual',compact('reporte'));
```

al darle un dd($reporte) me da como resultado esto:

```
call sp_reportes(1,2020,10,0,null,null);
```

el cual si lo ejecuto en mi phpmyadmin me da el resultado sin problema.

pero en la aplicación me da este mensaje:

```
ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/App/resources/views/Reportes/reporte_mensual.blade.php)
```

los parametros del sp son:

```
in seleccion int,
    in anio int,
    in mes int,
    in personal int,
    in fechaini date,
    in fechafin date
```

PD.: Estoy usando mariadb version 10.4.10.
PD2.: En versiones de mysql antiguas tenía la costumbre de usar '' como valor null para tipo date, pero aqui no funciona.

este es el reporte_mensual.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Aportes</th>
                <th>Salidas</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($reporte as $rep)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$rep->fecha}}</td>
                    <td>{{$rep->aportes}}</td>
                    <td>{{$rep->salidas}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                @foreach($total as $tot)
                <tr class="table-primary">
                    <td>Total</td>
                    <td>{{$tot->aportes}}</td>
                    <td>{{$tot->salidas}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <div class="text-center">
        <a href="{{action('ReportesController@index')}} " class="btn btn-link">Regresar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Puedes adjuntar el archivo reporte_mensual.blade.php? Según el mensaje que mandas, el error está en un foreach dentro de ese archivo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo obtener el resultado de un procedimiento almacenado en Laravel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383602/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-el-resultado-de-un-procedimiento-almacenado-en-laravel)

Comment: Tu sintaxis para ejecutar un sp no parece correcta

Comment: entonces como crees que debería de ir @BetaM? porque en phpmyadmin si funciona y en cualquier gestor de mysql

Comment: ya lo adjunte @CarlosCórdova

Comment: Gracias BetaM se solucionó con un DB::select, debí imaginarmelo, siempre gracias.